# What is the meaning of comma separated names in brackets - as a binding?

Tags: haskell

In a document (https://riptutorial.com/Download/haskell-language.pdf), in *Chapter 5: Arrows*, I encountered the following example:

```
spaceAround :: Double -> [Double] -> Double
spaceAround x ys = minimum greater - maximum smaller  where (greater, smaller) = partition (>x) ys
```

What does the expression `(greater, smaller)` mean?

Comment: That's a very awful "book" (note that the author admits to pinching the entire content from [a StackOverflow dump](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z)). Try [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The `partition` function returns a pair or 2-element tuple as its result. Assigning that tuple to `(greater, smaller)` assigns values of the first and second elements of the pair to the two variables `greater` and `smaller` respectively.

If you are familiar with the `let... in` syntax, another way of writing this function would be as follows:

```
spaceAround2 :: Double -> [Double] -> Double
spaceAround2 x ys = 
    let myPair = partition (>x) ys
        greater = fst myPair
        smaller = snd myPair
    in minimum greater - maximum smaller
```

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism is just called pattern matching.

It is eplained here:

> Syntax in Functions
>
> Pattern matching
>
> ...
>
> Where!?
>
> ...
>
> You can also use where bindings to pattern match! We could have
> rewritten the where section of our previous function as:
>
> ```
>   ...
>   where bmi = weight / height ^ 2  
>   (skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
> ```
>
> ...

Source: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

Hence, in the example that is provided with the question, the result of the function *partition* is split into the elements by mattern mathching.

Further tested example:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
        print e1
        print e2
        print e3

(e1, e2, e3) = (1, "Hello", "World!")
```

...it prints:

```
1
"Hello"
"World!"
```

Comment: No, this mechanism doesn't have anything to do with `-XRecordWildCards`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That might be. But if the splitting has nothing to do with RecordWildCards - would you mind to state how this mechanism is called - that splits the tuple into the elements?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Dont mind. I found out by my self.